# how much does my bag weigh

Tags: logical-deduction

I have a bag of money and I've offered to give you the bag if you can estimate its weight closer to the true weight than I can. In order to help us, I bring out 2 scales, both of which are inaccurate, but will break after weighing the bag and giving out a reading (they can only be used once). How would you estimate the weight of the bag?

*This question is a little statistics heavy, but hopefully it fits on the site.*

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do I know your estimate?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore - no, we write our estimates on a piece of paper and share afterwards.

Comment: Are you allowed to add to or subtract from the bag's contents when you weigh it?

Comment: Do we each get to use one scale? Or have you already estimated so that I can use both scales? Or are the weighing public so we both use the same outcomes for our estimates?

Comment: Since there is only [tag:logical-deduction] tag and no any other tag, I think this question is lacking many assumptions. For example, how do "I" and "you" behave? Do we both have perfect logic, and both want to keep the gold? How do the two scales behave? Are their outcomes independent random variables with the same distribution? Without any logical assumption, the [tag:logical-deduction] tag makes no sense as there is nothing to deduce from.

Answer (score 4):

MichaelMaggs' answer is generally reasonable but misses one vital point:

> You should bias your estimate upwards, e.g. by giving more weight to the larger of the two readings on the scales. This is because you are not trying to optimise your probability of winning, but rather the expected value of your winnings, and a heavier bag is likely to be more valuable.

Comment: Not at all sure that is right. If both scales are working and have normally distributed errors, then the mean is objectively the best guess for this specific bag. If you add a systematic bias towards the heavier value the chance of winning it will fall. Expectation value doesn't seem to come into it, as there is only one bag available, and only once chance to win it. We must optimise for that.

Comment: Some biased estimate might be needed if we knew something about the properties of the scales, or the sophistication of our opponent, but we don't. Could you clarify your answer by quantifying the level of bias towards the heavier measurement that you recommend?

Comment: @MichaelMaggs - If we're being somewhat handwavy about this, I think this argument of biasing upwards has some merit. In a simple example, if we weigh the bags and the two scales are widely off, we may randomly pick one of the two, and would be advantaged to pick the higher value scale

Comment: @MichaelMaggs: Actually, your first sentence is false. If the weighings are i.i.d with the correct mean, then the mean is **not** objectively the best. But your second sentence is true. The correct answer is to bootstrap to estimate the mean and standard deviation and back-calculate the optimal guess based on our prior assumption on the distribution, which **will** be higher than the mean if the two weighings differ.

Comment: @user21820: Thanks. The experimental physics approach to this sort of situation would no doubt be: first, where information is missing, make some explicit assumptions; second, calculate the objectively best solution based on those stated assumptions.

Comment: @MichaelMaggs The point is, best by what objective? Suppose our estimate for the weight of the bag is 100g plus a normally-distributed error with standard deviation 10g, and we win if we are within 5g of the true weight. (Yes, this is a different problem, but at least it's sufficiently specified that we can work out a precise answer.) The probability of winning is maximised by guessing 100g, of course, but guessing 101g gives a higher expected value.

Comment: @user21820: Yes, that makes sense on those assumptions. There are two possible objectives, and the question leaves open which is 'best': (a) maximising the probability of winning that specific bag and (b) maximising expected monetary winnings. One of the several issues which makes the puzzle out of scope for PSE I would imagine.

Answer (score 3):

We apparently know nothing at all about the accuracy of the scales, and we can't use any of the usual experimental methods such as repeated measurements or calibration to find out more. Assuming that both measurements seem physically reasonable, there's nothing for it but to take their arithmetic mean as the 'best' value.  I've no idea how you will come up with your figure, but it seems sensible to assume that you will likely go for that 'best' value.

> Since I need to get *closer* to the true value than you (I don't get the bag if our estimates are the same), I'd make my estimate a small amount above or below the mean in order to break the tie.

But there are exceptions.

> If any measurement is physically unreasonable, that has to be ignored, not included in the mean. So, if one value is evidently wrong (eg if one of the scales shows zero) the best estimate is simply the other.

> Also, if the measurements are entirely incompatible with each other, it makes no sense statistically to take the mean. One of the scales must be hopelessly inaccurate, and the best I can do is to select whichever of the two values seems subjectively more likely.

> And in every case, if I think you might reason in the same way, I'd add or subtract a small amount, to break any potential tie.

Comment: There is no logical reason that the arithmetic mean is the "best" value, as there is no assumption on the behaviors of the two scales. In view of the [tag:logical-deduction] tag, this answer definitely doesn't make sense. In fact I wonder whether the question itself makes sense.

Comment: If you walked into a room and were faced with _exactly_ the situation of the problem, with no further information at all, I'd contend that taking the mean is what you would want to do. In that sense it's the 'best' value to choose. But of course, that may change if there are other thus-far unstated facts or assumptions. And I agree that the tagging is incorrect, as this is not in its present form really a logical-deduction puzzle. I doubt it is even intended to be: look at the history to see the first version.

Comment: Aha, thanks a lot for mentioning the history, which I didn't check. It's probably [tag:open-ended], which is no longer acceptable on this site ...

Comment: I do hope that the author will come back and tighten the assumptions we are supposed to work to.

Comment: @WhatsUp - Ah you're right, it fits better into open-ended and is out of scope. I wasn't sure if it was in scope and was just trying to find the tag that fit best. I'm not totally convinced that there isn't a correct answer though and I think this one is quite close, given the lack of information and thus lack of potential actions

Answer (score -1):

Given no extra information, I think it's fair to assume a Gaussian distribution of the scales, which means the mean should estimate the true value but the variance may be different. I think I would estimate the answer based as a weighted sum of the inverse of the variance of each scale

Comment: How would you find the variance of each scale, given you only have 1 weighing?

Comment: @nzwu Hmm I did not see the 1 weighing part

Comment: Interesting that a question asked by a brand new account created today is immediately answered by another brand new account created today that has the exact same (presumably ip-based) gravatar.

Comment: @cap They have consecutive id numbers too.